# Flutter: Unable to load assets for flutter_map

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, fluttermap, flutter-assetimage

I'm building an app where I embed a map using flutter_map.
I have downloaded offline tiles, but they cannot be loaded from the assets folder because the following error appears: [Error](https://haste.l4zs.de/higubavide.sql).
flutter_map itself gives the following errors: [Error](https://haste.l4zs.de/ecenuqeguy.apache)

My main.dart file: [Main Dart File](https://haste.l4zs.de/kuximinine.properties)

My pubspec.yaml file: [Pubspec.yaml](https://haste.l4zs.de/etuzugacux.yaml)

My folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply adding each folder individually.
Apparently the developers of Flutter don't offer any other option at the moment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).